# Windows batch file to sort files into separate directories based on types specified in a csv

Tags: windows, batch-file

I hate to ask this, but I'm in a time crunch and I'm hoping someone with more familiarity with batch can help me much quicker than I could learn all of the syntax myself.

I'm in an unfortunate situation where I have an environment with a bare Windows XP install that I cannot install any additional software to.

I need to sort a directory of several thousand files into a handful of folders based on a type specified in a csv file:

```
fileName1,type1
fileName2,type2
fileName3,type4
fileName4,type1
```

The csv file does not include the file extensions, but there are no files with the same name and different extensions.

I need a script that will put each file into a directory named the same as the specified types so that when I'm finished I have one directory for each type and all the files that match that type (as specified in the csv) are inside.

Can anyone provide some direction on how to accomplish this with a batch script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2" %i in (types.csv) do @move %i.* %j
```

The @ suppresses the echoing of the text of the move command, although the move command still lists the files that it moves.

Comment: Thank you! This works if the directories for each type already exist. Is there a way to get it to create the directory if it does not exist? Currently it just renames the file to the type name if the directory does not exist.

Comment: @ratherOCD You could perform an initial pass using `mkdir %j` although mkdir will warn if the directory already exists.

Comment: @ratherOCD: `for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2" %i in (types.csv) do (if not exist %j md %j) & @move %i.* %j`