# Windows Batch sript that moves files based on a (partial char string) looking it up in a CSV/txt file

Tags: windows, shell

What I'm looking for might be a variation of this solution: [Windows batch file to sort files into separate directories based on types specified in a csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158846/windows-batch-file-to-sort-files-into-separate-directories-based-on-types-specif)

My Situation: a batch process in a server creates files that look like this: S0028513-010716-0932.txt. S stands for summary, the first five digits stand for a supplier, the last two before the hyphen stand for the Distribution Center. After the hyphen, there is the date and after the second hyphen the timestamp.

What I need to do is:

1. set a variable for the month/year (e.g. 0716) (this has been set with "set /P c:Please enter MMYY:"). *This part is done.*
2. create a folder with subfolders (e.g. 0716\PHARMA, 0716\MEDICAL, etc). *I've done this part.*
3. look up the supplier number in a CSV file (e.g. S00285 above) and
4. move the file to the corresponding folder based on MMYY\PHARMA, etc.

Points 3 and 4 are obvioulsy missing. A practical example: there are three folders where the files can be moved: PHARMA, MEDICAL and CONSUMER

The CSV file looks like this:

- S00285 CONSUMER
- S00286 PHARMA
- S00287 MEDICAL
- ...

What I want the script to do is to look up the month/year combination in variable c and take all files that correspond to this month/year and move them to the three folders according to the assignment in the CSV file.

Can this be done with standard Windows scripting? Sorry guys, I'm a novice as you can tell. I have only some very basic knowledge of BASH scripting.

Thank you a lot for any advice.

BR
Marcio

Comment: What version of Windows does this need to run on? It'll be way easier with [tag:powershell]

Comment: Hi Mathias. Windows 7 Pro. Powershell is surely a possibility, I just need to make sure that complete lays can execute the script. This should be no Problem, though. A powershell solution would be greatly appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This can fairly easily be accomplished with PowerShell

```
$FolderRoot = "E:\Target\Directory"

Set-Location $FolderRoot

# 1. Have user input month/year string
do{
    $MMYY = $(Read-Host 'Please enter MMYY').Trim()
} until ($MMYY -match '\d{4}')

# 2. Create directory
mkdir $MMYY

# ?. Gather input files for that year
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Filter S*.txt |Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match "S\d{7}-\d{2}$MMYY-\d{4}"}

# ?. load CSV file into hash table to easily look up supplier numbers
$SupplierLookupTable = @{}

# Assuming the csv has headers: Supplier,Industry
Import-Csv -Path E:\path\to\suppliers.csv |ForEach-Object {
    $SupplierLookupTable[$_.Supplier] = $_.Industry
}

foreach($File in $Files)
{
    # Grab the S and first 5 digits from the file name
    $Supplier = $File.BaseName.Substring(0,6)
    # 3. Look up the industry
    $Industry = $SupplierLookupTable[$Supplier]
    $Destination = Join-Path $MMYY $Industry
    # Create folder if it doesn't already exist
    if(-not (Test-Path $Destination))
    {
        mkdir $Destination
    }
    # 4. Move the file
    Move-Item $File.Fullname -Destination $Destination
}
```

Comment: Hi Mathias. Thanks a lot for the script. I'm trying to adapt it to my nees. I see a small poblem: in my work Laptop, I would need to have admin rights to sign the script or change the policy. I might get the permission. The problem is that I would need to be able to allow anyone in my department to run it. This might be quite difficult to get approved. The simple shell script wouldn't need this rights. Am I right?

Comment: @MCC1975 Depending on the version, you may be able to bypass the ExecutionPolicy for the duration of a session with `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process`